# How to use connectionDidFinishDownloading:destinationURL: and connectionDidFinishLoading:

Tags: ios6, nsurlconnection, newsstand-kit, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I have implemented both the NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate delegate methods as given below.

The problem is that after connection:didReceiveResponse: ,  connectionDidFinishDownloading:destinationURL: is called but not connectionDidFinishLoading: Even connection:didReceiveData: is not called.

When I comment the NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate methods, the other three are called without any issues.

I have a NSURLConnections which gets JSON from server. The NSURLConnectionDataDownloading delegate methods are used by newsstand to download issues.

How do i manage this?

Here are all the delegate methods than I am implementing

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didWriteData:(long long)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(long long)totalBytesWritten expectedTotalBytes:(long long)expectedTotalBytes {

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishDownloading:(NSURLConnection *)connection destinationURL:(NSURL *)destinationURL {

}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

}
```

Here is my .h file

```
@interface FirstTopViewController : UIViewController <NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate, NSURLConnectionDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

This is how I am connecting to server to get JSON

```
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

This is the code for downloading an issue if needed

```
NSURLRequest *urlReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
NKAssetDownload *asset = [currentIssue addAssetWithRequest:urlReq];
[asset downloadWithDelegate:self];
```

The problem is with the call to get JSON from server. Issue downloading works fine.

Answer (score 2):

NSURLConnectionDataDelegate define delegate methods used for loading data to memory. 
NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate: delegate methods used to perform resource downloads directly to a disk file.

Then if you implemented connectionDidFinishDownloading:destinationURL: in your delegate. That will inform NSURLConnection you want to download the data to a disk file other than to memory as NSData. The 
NSURLConnectionDataDelegate method won't get called. If you eliminate connectionDidFinishDownloading:destinationURL: from your delegate class implementation, connection:DidReceiveData: will get called instead.

For your case, implement two helper delegates for different usage.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to get your JSON data in `-connection:didReceiveData:`, you need to set the delegate to an object which implements NSURLConnectionDataDelegate; when you want to download an issue to a file, the delegate needs to be an object that implements NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate. A single class can't do both at once.

This is not explained very well in the NSURLConnection docs, but the comments in `NSURLConnection.h` make it a little more explicit:

> An NSURLConnection may be used for loading of resource data
>   directly to memory, in which case an
>   NSURLConnectionDataDelegate should be supplied, or for
>   downloading of resource data directly to a file, in which case
>   an NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate is used.  The delegate is
>   retained by the NSURLConnection until a terminal condition is
>   encountered.  These two delegates are logically subclasses of
>   the base protocol, NSURLConnectionDelegate.